# c# paypal cancel subscription server side

Tags: paypal, duplicates, paypal-subscriptions, cancellation

My website users need to buy plans with paypal subscription. 
A use can switch between plans. In order for a user not to have duplicate subscriptions I need to be able to delete the old ones once a user is sign up for a new subscription.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [PayPal Standard Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/) you won't be able to do this, unfortunately.

You will need to switch to the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) with [Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/?mark=recurring%20payments).  Then you can use the APIs to manage the profiles with these calls:

- [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)